# How to add an option to a html select, from input received from the user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select with client names that is populated from a SQL database, that part works fine, but occasionally it is necessary to add a new client. So I want a button that displays a popup where the user can provide the new client name and have it added to the select as a new option. Below is the relevant code that I have tried. The problem is that when either button is pressed on the prompt it causes the form to submit and reloads the page. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action = "AddNewJob.php" method = "post">
...
<td><?php echo $dropdown3 ?><button onclick="myFunction()">Add new client</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var client = prompt("Please enter client name", "New client");

    if ((client != null) && (!client.equals("New client"))) {
        var select = document.getElementById("Client");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(client, client);
        document.getElementById('newclientfield').value = client;
    }
}
</script></td>
...
<p><input type="hidden" id="newclientfield" value="" /></p>
<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnAdd"></p>

</form>
```

$dropdown3 is the select that is created in PHP from the SQL database
EDIT:
Here is the code for $dropdown3:

```
$Clients = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM tblClients");
$i = 0;
$rownum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($i < $rownum){

    mysqli_data_seek($result, $i);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $Clients[] = $row[0];
    $i++;

}

$dropdown3 = "<select size=\"1\" name=\"Client\" id=\"Client\">"; 
$i = 0;
    while($i < count($Clients)){

    $dropdown3 .= "\r\n<option value = '" . $Clients[$i] . "'>" . $Clients[$i] . "</option>";
    $i++;
    }  
$dropdown3 .= "\r\n</select>";
```

That part works fine.

Comment: Very well, can we have the code of `$dropdown3` then?

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your "Add New Client" button.

Comment: Adding the `type="button"` has solved the submitting issue, thanks @Pointy. Now it seems my adding to the select doesn't work. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Well `client.equals()` looks wrong; that's not how you compare strings in JavaScript.

Comment: That fixed the issue, thanks very much. Turns out swapping between Java and javaScript causes some issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code for the button that requests user input and then adds the option to the select (as well as a hidden field for POST purposes so it can be added to the database).

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add new client</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var client = prompt("Please enter client name", "New client");

    if ((client != null) && (client != "New client")) {
        var select = document.getElementById("Client");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(client, client);
        document.getElementById('newclientfield').value = client;
        select.selectedIndex=select.options.length - 1;
    }
}
</script>
```